# Kernel root node of dtb with compat variable

Tags: linux, kernel, device-tree

I'm reading the code of linux kernel.
In drvier/of/fdt.c, there's a function as below.

```
const void * __init of_flat_dt_match_machine(const void *default_match,
        const void * (*get_next_compat)(const char * const**))
{
    const void *data = NULL;
    const void *best_data = default_match;
    const char *const *compat;
}
```

I have a question about a value of "compat" variable.
It seems that the compat would have start address of string which means root node in dtb.
Here's my question, how the compat would have the array without initialization like allocating memory.

If my question is weird or need more details, please let me know.